# Testing NativeAOT with Mock Lambda Test Tool results in error

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, .net-7.0

I have am using .NET 7 NativeAOT to write an AWS Lambda Function. I am trying to use the Mock Lambda Test Tool to test it. I'm not sure if I need to use the "Test Function" or "Executable Assembly"? How do I test it with the tool locally?

I'm using this input:

```
{
    "Id": "test"
}
```

"Test Function" results in the following error:

```
System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.IO.MemoryStream' cannot be converted to type 'Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents.APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest'.
   at System.RuntimeType.CheckValue(Object& value, ParameterCopyBackAction& copyBack, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.CheckArguments(Span`1 copyOfParameters, IntPtr* byrefParameters, Span`1 shouldCopyBack, ReadOnlySpan`1 parameters, RuntimeType[] sigTypes, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Amazon.Lambda.TestTool.Runtime.LambdaExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ExecutionRequest request) in C:\build\Tools\LambdaTestTool\src\Amazon.Lambda.TestTool\Runtime\LambdaExecutor.cs:line 61
```

Executable Assembly does not appear to do anything.

I'm using VS Code in Linux. Here's my Lambda Function:

```
using Amazon.Lambda.Core;
using Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport;
using Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents;
using Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace DocGenerator;

public class Function
{
    private static async Task Main()
    {
        Func<APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest, ILambdaContext, Task<APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyResponse>> handler = FunctionHandler;
        await LambdaBootstrapBuilder.Create(handler, new SourceGeneratorLambdaJsonSerializer<LambdaFunctionJsonSerializerContext>(options => {
                options.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
            }))
            .Build()
            .RunAsync();
    }

    public static async Task<APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyResponse> FunctionHandler(APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest apigProxyEvent, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("test");
        context.Logger.LogLine("test");

        var test = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(apigProxyEvent.Body, LambdaFunctionJsonSerializerContext.Default.Test);

        return new APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyResponse
                {
                    Body = test.Id.ToUpper(),
                    StatusCode = 200,
                };
    }
}

[JsonSerializable(typeof(APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest))]
[JsonSerializable(typeof(APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyResponse))]
[JsonSerializable(typeof(Test))]
public partial class LambdaFunctionJsonSerializerContext : JsonSerializerContext
{

}

public class Test {
    public string Id {get; set;}
}
```

I used the samples here to create my function: https://github.com/aws-samples/serverless-dotnet-demo/tree/main/src/NET7Native

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this today as well. And off and on for the last week.

First, run the Lambda test tool. In the browser, on the page that opens, go to the Documentation tab. It's got info about testing an executable-based Lambda. The AOT Lambda is built as an executable, so we have to use that to do this.

It involves updating your launchSettings.json, to add a configuration for doing this. The issue is that F5 without adding this will throw some exception about a bad URI, and it seems to be that when the Lambda exe starts up it doesn't know what AWS endpoint to connect to. The launchSettings info in the documentation provides that, in the form a localhost address listening on (in my case) port 5050.

So add that launch config there, make sure the test tool is already running, select those launch settings, then F5. The Lambda exe will run, and just be a blank console window (maybe if you log things to console you would see those messages as well). Then the test tool's Executable Assembly tab is where you would run your tests from.

I confirmed this with a fresh .NET 7 AOT project that just echoes your input as a response but now that I got that working I'm confident I'll manage to get it working on my actual code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this was recently added to the README which should help

https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/blob/master/Tools/LambdaTestTool/README.md#testing-executable-assemblies

This comes from this issue: https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/issues/1539

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34687434)